# How to update Tax info of Paypal Order?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I am using C# .net Core MVC and for Paypal V2 i am using https://github.com/paypal/Checkout-NET-SDK

I am not able to update the Tax info of Order after user login & approval through paypal (before final order submission).

I created Order using following

```
var request = new OrdersCreateRequest();
request.Prefer("return=representation");
request.RequestBody(order);
response = await client().Execute(request);
var statusCode = response.StatusCode;
Order result = response.Result<Order>();
```

Then control goes to PayPal & asks for user login at Paypal. The user login and clicks the "Continue" on Paypal and the control comes back to my Application.

At this point, i need to update the Tax info in order but don't know how to do it. I was looking at following links for Help.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integration-features/update-order-details/

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2#orders_patch

so I looked at Patch Order to update the Tax. I tried "OrdersPatchRequest" with following Patch code in c#

```
 new Patch<Object>
 {
     Op= "replace",
     Path= "/purchase_units/@reference_id=='default'/amount",
     Value ="{\"breakdown\":{\"item_total\":{\"currency_code\":\"USD\",\"value\":\"1\"},\"shipping\":{\"currency_code\":\"USD\",\"value\":\"3\"},\"tax_total\":{\"currency_code\":\"USD\",\"value\":\"2\"}},\"currency_code\":\"USD\",\"value\":\"6\"}"
 }
```

The Patch value looks like below in formatted form

```
{
    "breakdown":
    {
        "item_total":{"currency_code":"USD","value":"1"},
        "shipping":{"currency_code":"USD","value":"3"},
        "tax_total":{"currency_code":"USD","value":"2"}
    },
    "currency_code":"USD",
    "value":"6"
}
```

but its failing with following error

```
{"name":"INVALID_REQUEST","details":[{"field":"/purchase_units/@reference_id=='default'/amount","value":"{\"breakdown\":{\"item_total\":{\"currency_code\":\"USD\",\"value\":\"1\"},\"shipping\":{\"currency_code\":\"USD\",\"value\":\"3\"},\"tax_total\":{\"currency_code\":\"USD\",\"value\":\"2\"}},\"currency_code\":\"USD\",\"value\":\"6\"}","location":"body","issue":"INVALID_PARAMETER_VALUE","description":"The value of a field is invalid."}],"message":"Request is not well-formed, syntactically incorrect, or violates schema.","debug_id":"1879d34e23fc4","links":[{"href":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#error-INVALID_PARAMETER_VALUE","rel":"information_link","method":"GET"}]}
```

Any idea why its failing ? Please Help.

(* Patch Value & Error Message updated above)

Answer (score 0):

Your patch value:

```json
"{\"breakdown\":{\"item_total\":{\"currency_code\":\"USD\",\"value\":\"1\"},\"tax_total\":\"USD\",\"value\":\"2\"},\"shipping\":{\"currency_code\":\"USD\",\"value\":\"3\"}},\"currency_code\":\"USD\",\"value\":\"6\"}"
```

Is more legibly rendered as:

```json
{
    "breakdown": {
        "item_total": {
            "currency_code": "USD",
            "value": "1"
        },
        "tax_total": "USD",
        "value": "2"
    },
    "shipping": {
        "currency_code": "USD",
        "value": "3"
    }
    }, "currency_code": "USD", "value": "6"
}
```

Which as you can see is not valid, hence the error

Comment: My apologies ....but i did some mistake while pasting the Patch value and error earlier. i have updated the Patch Value and also the error message i am getting in the Original post. Please check them now

Comment: I'm having a similar problem. Did you ever find a solution to this please?